# Form Using React Hook Forms showing undefined for Custom Input Component Fields

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-hook-form, react-forms

```
    <div className="App">
        <div>
            <form
                onSubmit={handleSubmit((data) => {
                    console.log(data);
                })}
                className="hey"
            >
                <h2>Log in</h2>
                <Input
                    style="input"
                    placeholder="Email"
                    type="email"
                    {...register("Email")}
                />
                <Input
                    style="input"
                    placeholder="Password"
                    type="password"
                    {...register("Password")}
                />
                <Button style="button neon-transparent" type="submit" name="Log In" />
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

I am currently in the process of trying to create a form using the react hooks form library, when I click submit on this form the object of the form gets console logged but the two fields appear as undefined when values have been put into each field. I know this is most likely an issue custom components because when I created the form with traditional input fields it worked no problem.

I am very new to this library, if anyone has an answer for how to use this library with custom components it would be much appreciated.

Here is the Input component as well:

```
    type InputProps = {
    type: string,
    placeholder?: string,
    style: string
}

export const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
  return (
    <input className={props.style} type={props.type} placeholder={props.placeholder} />
  )
}
```

Comment: where are your Input component coming from?

Comment: They're in a seperate TSX file would you like to see?

Comment: Do you have the `register` function defined above? If possible could you show the whole component?

Comment: Yes i use this const { register, handleSubmit } = useForm<LoginFormModel>();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your input component to the following:

```
export const Input = (props: InputProps) => {
   const {style, type, placeholder, ...others} = props;
   return (
        <input className={style} type={type} placeholder={placeholder} {...others} />
   );
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, is there a way to do it that doesnt required destructing the prop?

Comment: sure, you can send className instead of style as prop from your main component. Then you simply use <input {...props} />